# Create heatmap with PSTricks or TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, plot

I have a huge amount of 2D-coordinates, associated with a value, e.g.:

```
  x   |   y   | value
27.50   52.15   12.51
61.83   13.32   57.56
36.23   21.83   41.73
40.46   85.67   25.20
...
```

The data is not tabular and I Want the points between two data-points to be interpolated in some way (which way is not really clear, yet)

I want to preset the data as heatmap like this:
[image: heatmap-example]

Is there any ready-to-use package for PSTricks or TikZ to do it?

Comment: Because of your **huge** data amount I would suggest you to use maybe `gnuplot` with the `cairolatex` or `epslatex` terminal. For an example, see the last script in my answer to [Big data surface plots: Call gnuplot from tikz to generate bitmap and include automatically?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131106/33933). You would have to use `dgrid3d` to resample your scattered data.

Comment: see http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=pst-plot/3D/contour for such contour plots. The data can be an array of arrays, the reason why you can have huge data sets.

Answer (score 11):

You can also use the `pgfplots` package, as I show below. I used the same number of data points as Herbert, as well as the default `matlab` color map. You should compile the following code with `LuaLaTeX` because it needs a lot of memory. Since it takes a **lot** of time (about 2 minutes on my PC), it's better to compile it once and then insert the `pdf` file of your graph as an image.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    colormap/jet,
    colorbar,
    view={0}{90}]
    \addplot3[surf,shader=flat] file {data-map.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you use the same data structure as the OP or the on in Herbert's answer? Because I have the same three columns as the OP and I don't get interpolation.

Comment: @iomartin It seems to wort if you remove all non-data text from the .data file. But If you have too many data, you get an *TeX capacity exceeded* error...

Answer (score 7):

An example with a data set of more than 65000 records (http://tug.org/PSTricks/pst-plot/3D/contourN.data).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}
\psset{unit=1.5cm}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-3,-3)(3,3)
\pstContour[colored]{contourN.data}
\end{pspicture}

\medskip
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](-3,-3)(3,3)
\pstContour{contourN.data}
\end{pspicture}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Will there be holes in it if i don't cover the area completely dense with tabular-like coordinates?

Comment: Only the single data record must have three values

Comment: Your examples gives me a "! Undefined control sequence.
l.12 \pstContour
                {contourN.data}". Using MikTex 2.9

Comment: As I wrote you need the latest pstricks-add.tex.

Answer (score 6):

There is `tikzDevice` for R which will generate TikZ code for a plot created in R. So, if you use R to create your heat map (say, using `ggplot2`'s `geom_density2d()`), you also get the TikZ code with little effort. There is a [learning curve](http://blog.nguyenvq.com/blog/2010/10/22/creating-even-nicer-publishable-embeddable-plots-using-tikzdevice-in-r-for-use-with-latex/), though.

However, this kind of image should be included as a (perhaps high-resolution) raster image in your document, as the vector version might take a long time to render. So you can create a TikZ version of the plot, compile it to PDF and then convert to PNG at the required resolution/pixel density.

Comment: This makes the learning curve a tad easier -> www.itc.nl/~rossiter/teach/R/LDA.pdf‎

Comment: @ForkrulAssail: Can't find anything under the URL you provided. 404.

Comment: Sorry, seems they disabled direct linking -> try http://www.itc.nl/~rossiter/pubs/list.html then look for Literate Data Analysis. It's about the 3rd one down under R applications.