# Plotting Heat Map - problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I'm trying to plot a heat map with [this data](http://www.wikiupload.com/XIU19M9956ZIFAG). I expected to create a heat map like the one given in the answer of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133882/create-heatmap-with-pstricks-or-tikz). (Although my plot will be only a quarter of it 0 to 90 degrees). But when I run my code all I get is this picture.[image]

What am I doing wrong? I thought that the code will interpolate the data in-between.

Here is my MWE

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    colormap/jet,
    colorbar,
    view={0}{90}]
    \addplot3[surf,shader=flat] file {TEMP_dummy.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How do I sort this problem?

Comment: Hard to reproduces without sample data.

Comment: @cfr: I have attached the data. See the question- "this data" takes you to the link for downloading data.

Comment: @SaravanaKumar, I get an "Sorry, File not found!" error when trying to download your data ...