# Fast(er) way of generating stacked 2d-plots in 3d

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

I have quite a lot of 2d-data I would like to display in a 3d-plot, similar to the figure below (drawn in Python):
[image]
Until now I created those figures in pgfplots with `addplot3`, but for an increasing amount of data the compilation slows down significantly, until LaTeX runs out of memory. Of course I could create those figures in Python, for example, but with the drawback of either having to re-create the labels and ticks in tikz afterwards to match the font style of the document, or loose the scaling capability totally when keeping them in the figure. Tikzscale is a functionality I do not want to loose, especially after my document can either be two-column or single-column wide, and therefore I would prefer automatic rescaling of the figure.

Therefore, are there other (ideally similarly integrated as tikz) options for drawing such plots, but with improved speed?

Comment: Approximately, how many points are there per one 2d plot?

Comment: @g.kov: Around 1-2k per plot, to properly resolve oscillations. Python handles them just fine, it's rather pgfplots which needs some time

Comment: Have you tried the [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/) as an alternative?

Comment: Not yet. Can I integrate it the same way as pgfplots-files?

Comment: Yes, there are several options for this,
it's deeply integrated with (La)TeX. 
Check out some answers [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/asymptote),
perhaps you could find something suitable.

Comment: Data is stored in a file, but plotting is still extremely slow @JohnKormylo

Comment: The only other option is to reduce the number of points.  The human eye can only resolve to about 0.01 relative.

Comment: Try `[row predicate/.code={\ifodd#1\relax\else\pgfplotstableuserowfalse\fi}]` (page 43 of pgfplotstable manual).

Comment: Consider use `knitr` because then (1) you can integrate R language  in LaTeX documents (,Rnw files), and  (2) R can make nice 3D plot with  huge amounts of data ([example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/467161/11604)),  and moreover (3) `knitr` have the option `cache=TRUE` so you can compile the .Rnw  file many times but the R graph is only complied once if the R data are not changed.